How to increase hit box for TextEditor?
I would like to increase the hit box for my TextEditor, but currently is very very small.
I will paste the code below so you can have a look. Thanks !
    var messageView: some View {
        Text(currentText)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding(10)
        .overlay(
            TextEditor(text: $currentText)
                .rchFont(.rchBody)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .focused($isTextEditorFocused)
                .scrollDisabled(true)
                .tint(.textDefault)
                .padding(.horizontal, 17)
        )
    }


What is a hit box?
